# Clean up space used by internal LOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, blob

I have a table with a CLOB column which is stored as internal LOB. The data in this column becomes obsolete quickly (within matter of days), and is never accessed afterwards.

I wonder whether nullifying this column on regular basis will be enough to let Oracle to reuse the space. E.g. have a scheduler job which would  `UPDATE my_table set clob_col =NULL WHERE date_col < sysdate -7` every day.

I'm using Oracle 12c if that matters.

Comment: It might be a good idea to change that to `WHERE date_col > sysdate - 14 AND date_col < sysdate - 7` - just to make sure that you're not trying to `UPDATE` every single row older than 7 days, when (generally) every row older than 8 days will have `clob_col` set to `NULL`.